# GPIO ports on STM32F4 Discovery?

Tags: port, stm32, gpio, stm32f4discovery

i've seen on STM32F4 Programming Manual that GPIO ports are from A to K. but in some slides i've read that are 5 ports (A to E). What these ports (F to K) do ? These are dedicated for some else ?

Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ports depends on the pin count of the specific STM32F4 model you're using. Each port has at most 16 pins, so models with, say 64 pins, will have less ports (around 4 to 5) than models with 176 pins (10 or possibly 11 ports). The datasheet indicates which peripherals are tied to which specific pins and ports, but in principle there are no "special" ports.

Comment: I've verified that, my STM32F4 model has 9 GPIO ports. Thank you for the info :)